# How to get Custom Post ID by adding filter to child theme's function

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, customization, filters, actions

How to get Custom Post ID by adding code to child theme's function. The following code works fine for the regular post, but can't figure out for the custom post types.

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'revealid_add_id_column', 5 );
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'revealid_id_column_content', 5, 2 );

function revealid_add_id_column( $columns ) {
   $columns['revealid_id'] = 'ID';
   return $columns;
}

function revealid_id_column_content( $column, $id ) {
   if( 'revealid_id' == $column ) {
   echo $id;
 }
}
```

Comment: Have your read the [`manage_$post_type_posts_columns`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns) doc? Your custom post type is called custom ??

Comment: @Laxmana, can you please give me the code, I try to read it and didn't understand well. My custom post type is :- $estate_property. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'id_data' );
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'id_column'  );
function id_column( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['id'] = 'ID';
    return $defaults;
}
function id_data( $column_name ) {
    global $post;
    switch ( $column_name ) {
    case 'id':
        echo $post->ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works fine for the regular posts, but it is not showing/working on the custom post type

Comment: I attached image in previous comments,please check it .It's in  custom posttype.Your code works fine in my custom posttype. Have you added any other condition?

Comment: I used Reveal ID plugin and it works fine on my custom post types. But I tend use less plugins. Therefore I assume that there must be missing something. I am using WP residence theme.

Comment: Your code works absolutely fine in custom posttype, without using  'Reveal ID plugin' ,may be in theme or in any plugin there is condition that's why it is not working.

Comment: I am trying to figure it out, and once I know the answer. I will let you know. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

For custom post types there are the corresponding filters [`manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column) and [`manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column) where `{$post_type}` is your custom post name (`$post_type` variable in [`register_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)).

I assume, as you said in comments, that your custom post type is called `estate_property`.

So:

```
add_filter( 'manage_estate_property_posts_columns', 'revealid_add_id_column', 5 );
add_action( 'manage_estate_property_posts_custom_column', 'revealid_id_column_content', 5, 2 );

function revealid_add_id_column( $columns ) {
   $columns['revealid_id'] = 'ID';
   return $columns;
}

function revealid_id_column_content( $column, $id ) {
   if( 'revealid_id' == $column ) {
   echo $id;
 }
}
```

This will work only for your custom post type. If you want to support multiple custom types read the doc of [manage_posts_custom_column](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column).

From [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column): Note that if the custom post type has `'hierarchical' => true`, then the correct action hook to use is [`manage_pages_custom_column`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_pages_custom_column).

Comment: Thank you. I put the code in the function.php - but nothing is happening. Am I missing something? Maybe custom post type has 'hierarchical' => true. Can you plz tell me the next step